# UIButton font size at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am working in a small iOS application where I have to change the font size for UIButton's according to device. I can use auto layout and change the UIButton frame according to device but the font size remains same. I dont wanna check the conditions for device because my application is gonna run on iPad and iPhone and landscape and portrait mode. And that makes me to check 12 conditions which is not a good practice.

Basically I dont want to set the font by using something like this

```
[_myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:40.0f]] ;
```

I have googled about it but I couldn't find anything which can fix my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
[[_myButton titleLabel] setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES] ;
```

**Edited:**
[image]
[image]

Here is the attached screen shots for my problem. I hope this will help to understand my problem.

Comment: why down vote ? If there s nothing to research then please help me to solve my problem ...

Answer (score 0):

`setAdjustsFontSizeToWidth` doesn't adjust the font based on device width, but on the bounds of the control - the button's label, in this case. If you want the font size to change with each device, try setting the button's leading and trailing space constraints higher in your storyboard or .xib file, but use that code you tried.

[image: Example of how to add a constraint]

Make sure the button is just big enough to fit the text, then select it and click the third button from the right in the lower right corner. Click the two horizontal red lines, with their values autofilled, and click "Add 2 Constraints". Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps:-

1) Create subclass of button.

2) Implement below method:-

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.titleLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work for me. when I use this, self.titleLabel.frame.size.height returns the height as '0'.

Comment: You shouldn't set a height constraint in this case.